# Zabbix triggers during network problems

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have a office zabbix server that is monitoring several distant servers. Most of the checks are via agents. When there are network problems in the office where zabbix server resides, I get lots of problem notifications (after restoring connection of course) of all services on all of the monitored servers. How can I disable triggers when there is no network connection on zabbix server? It comes to my mind to create trigger that is fired when it's not possible to ping google.com and to set it as action contidion, but would that be the most elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

Think you should use an external check to ping multiple hosts, create a trigger on that and make your other triggers depends on that one.
maybe this one is a good starting point for you:

https://github.com/UnsignedLong/zabbix-pingcheck

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what I think I'll do. Guess there is no some inbuild way of checking network connection.